# Get Outer Repeater Item from Inner Repeater

Tags: c#, data-binding, repeater

How do you get the outer repeater item from an inner repeater.  My outer repeater datasource has 3 items.  My inner repeater datasource has 7 items.  When I am iterating inside the inner repeater how do I get an item from the outer repeater?

My outer repeater datasource is a generic list.  One of the items in this list is a day (in number format).  My inner repeater is a list of int, 1 through 7 in this list.  I need some logic so that when I am iterating the list of days (in the inner).....if the outer has a value of 2 on the current recorded being iterated (so there is a match) I print something.

I hope that makes sense...

Thanks for any help or tips provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is just catch the outer item on databound and save it to a variable on the page.  Here I have two consecutive repeaters.  I save the year from the first repeater and then can reference it when I'm binding the second one.

```
    protected void repAnnualReport_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentYear = int.Parse(((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litLicenseYear")).Text);

        Repeater repLicenseLengths = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("repLicenseLengths");
        repLicenseLengths.DataSource = GetLicenseLengths(CurrentYear);
        repLicenseLengths.DataBind();
    }

    protected void repLicenseLengths_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentLength = int.Parse(((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litLicenseLength")).Text) * 365;

        Repeater repMonthlyReport = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("repMonthlyReport");
        repMonthlyReport.DataSource = new object[12];
        repMonthlyReport.DataBind();
    }
```

If what your binding to the first repeater is an class list or queryable, you can access the individual item like this in the first line.

```
SaveCurrentItem = (CurrentItemClass)e.Item.DataItem;
```

Comment: This is a good approach. Saving an object for use later is much better than trying to walk an object tree to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the hierarchy of .net controls from your inner repeater to the outer repeater, you can use the `NamingContainer` property to find your way up.

```
    protected void Repeater2_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {

            Repeater parentRepeater;

            // e.Item: the item/header/whatever template that kicked off this event
            // e.Item.NamingContainer: the owner of the item template (the innner repeater)
            // e.Item.NamingContainer.NamingContainer: the outer item template
            // e.Item.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.NamingContainer: the outer Repeater

            parentRepeater = (Repeater)e.Item.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.NamingContainer;

        }
    }
```

Otherwise if you're unsure of the structure or don't want the fixed reference like this, you can loop your way up through the `NamingContainer` until you hit something of type `Repeater` for the second time.